# Origin of "Great acts are made up of small deeds"

Tags: quote, taoism, chinese-philosophy

It is easy to find the author - Lao Tzu. But I lost hope trying to find the context, e.g. the book of the quote's origin. Hoping Stack Exchange philosophers can provide the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tao Te Ching, Chapter 63](https://books.google.it/books?id=5PgroQrhUFQC&pg=PA66).

See e.g. Wordsworth Edition with A.Waley translation,1997, page 66.

From a different translation: Lao Tzu, [Te-Tao Ching: A New Translation Based on the Recently Discovered Ma-wang-tui Texts (Robert Henricks editor, 1992, Ballantine Books)](https://books.google.it/books?id=jaEtWDLrukwC&printsec=frontcover):

> The most difficult things in the world begin as things that are easy;

> The largest things in the world arise from the minute.

Answer (score 1):

天下難事必作於易，天下大事必作於細
Tianxia  nanshi bi zuo yu yi
Tianxia dashi bi zuo yu xi

I would translate this: difficult things in the world must be done with ease, and great things in the world must be done done with care/(pay attention  to details)...
In the context of ch. 63 (:when) "difficult...with care" then the derails make the difficult task easy."
For example: when sages are well versed in the canons, it is easy for them to explain a difficult text to a layman.